# Get articulation from/to Rviz (Communicate with Rviz)

Tags: ros, rviz, package, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there !

I'm working with Rviz modeling my robot.

what I want to do is to change there articulations depending on real robot articulation !

I already get the articulation from real robot in ROS, then all what I have to do is to apply those articulations in RViz

=> So my question is how can I do that !

The final resulat that I want to get is in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vylvdHeoxWA):
Get exactly what I have in Rviz in real robot; like moving the real robot from Rviz !
NB: I already have a package that can get Cartesian coordinates and joints values from the real robot to ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207129/get-articulation-from/to-rviz-(communicate-with-rviz)/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2015-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have cartesian control of the robot already worked out, you can use an interactive marker in rviz to control the robot: http://wiki.ros.org/interactive_markers

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-04-15**:
I was thinking about Markers but actually I need little bit more details.

I already have an interactive marker in my arm-robot in the end effector.. so how could I start ? Do I need an interactive marker for each articulation ? Do I need to communicate with this/those markers ? if so how ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-04-15**:
I'm not sure about that, maybe someone with more experience in arm's can give you a pointer.